# Determine if NTFS volume was mounted outside

Tags: c++, windows, ntfs, mount

I have a software that is tracking an NTFS volume changes on a Windows OS using volume filter driver. I need to handle a condition when the volume gets mounted and modified outside of the OS where my driver is installed.

Is it possible to figure out the "last mount time" of the volume? or any other parameter allowing me to tell if the volume has been mounted outside of my driver control?

Comment: Do you mean mounted by Windows, or mounted by any tool (like a Linux NTFS driver)?

Comment: Any tool, but if you have Windows-only solution I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: Thank you, great hint! The only problem is that not every volume has USN journal enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a "last mount time", but there is a "log file open count". If you look at http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/ntfs/ntfs-64/kext/ntfs_logfile.h, you will see a `RESTART_AREA` structure like this:

> ```
> /* 40*/ le32 restart_log_open_count;/* A counter that gets incremented every
>                                      time the logfile is restarted which happens
>                                      at mount time when the logfile is opened.
>                                      When creating set to a random value.  Win2k
>                                      sets it to the low 32 bits of the current
>                                      system time in NTFS format (see time.h). */
> /* 44*/ le32 reserved;      /* Reserved/alignment to 8-byte boundary. */
> /* sizeof() = 48 (0x30) bytes */
> } __attribute__((__packed__)) RESTART_AREA;
> ```
>
> You can see that near the end of it is a `restart_log_open_count` that you can use to keep track of mounts. You would look at the value and compare it to a saved value. It should be equal to the saved value plus one. If so, it hasn't been mounted since you last had control.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just created a test program to check it - and indeed - the value gets incremented properly every time the volume is mounted.